# Remove groups if column contain more than x number of value in a list

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a list of element such as :

```
list_element=['Elephant','Monkey','Cow','Human','Bird','Snail','Snake','Donkey','Baboon','Orang-Outan']
```

and a dataframe

```
name  value
G1    Gr.1:4282399-4282564(+):Elephant
G1    SEQAHAHHE
G1    Zr.2:4282387-428245(-):Monkey
G1    GrA.2:42845-428289(+):Monkey
G1    QYEH897EH.3
G1    GrA2S2_ED:42845-4282789(+):Cow
G1    UDDKDDH6
G1    YDDIJBDIB778
G2    Gr.1:423663-4282542(-):Elephant
G2    Gr7E:423609-4282552(+):Elephant
G2    UEHHEE88E8E.2
G2    AP_UUD1_CU_OK-lQGGQ
G2    GrEH:423663-4282542(+):Baboon
G2    Gr7JE:42356-428257(+):Snail
G2    AP_UUD1_CU_OK-lQ8900
G2    ASGSG_E553:423663-4282542(-):Human
G3    GrA98_OK:42845-42867(+):Bird
G3    AGGAGA5567
```

I keep the `G1` because we have a total of `element <= 3` (Monkey, Elephant and Cow)

I remove `G2` because we have a total of `element > 3` (Elephant, Human, Snail and Baboon)

I keep `G3` because there is a total of `element <= 3` (Bird)

As you can see we fin the same pattern in value for element that contain a `'):'`

and the expected output would be :

```
name  value
G1    Gr.1:4282399-4282564(+):Elephant
G1    SEQAHAHHE
G1    Zr.2:4282387-428245(-):Monkey
G1    GrA.2:42845-428289(+):Monkey
G1    QYEH897EH.3
G1    GrA2S2_ED:42845-4282789(+):Cow
G1    UDDKDDH6
G1    YDDIJBDIB778
G3    GrA98_OK:42845-42867(+):Bird
G3    AGGAGA5567
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.str.extract` to extract the elements, then `groupby().nunique()` to count the number of unique elements:

```
s = (df['value'].str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(list_element)) )[0]
    .groupby(df['name'])
    .transform('nunique') )

df[s<=3]
```

Output:

```
   name                             value
0    G1  Gr.1:4282399-4282564(+):Elephant
1    G1                         SEQAHAHHE
2    G1     Zr.2:4282387-428245(-):Monkey
3    G1      GrA.2:42845-428289(+):Monkey
4    G1                       QYEH897EH.3
5    G1    GrA2S2_ED:42845-4282789(+):Cow
6    G1                          UDDKDDH6
7    G1                      YDDIJBDIB778
16   G3      GrA98_OK:42845-42867(+):Bird
17   G3                        AGGAGA5567
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: len(set(x[x['value'].str.contains(':')]['value'].str.split(':').str[-1].values)) <= 3)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   name                             value
0    G1  Gr.1:4282399-4282564(+):Elephant
1    G1                         SEQAHAHHE
2    G1     Zr.2:4282387-428245(-):Monkey
3    G1      GrA.2:42845-428289(+):Monkey
4    G1                       QYEH897EH.3
5    G1    GrA2S2_ED:42845-4282789(+):Cow
6    G1                          UDDKDDH6
7    G1                      YDDIJBDIB778
16   G3      GrA98_OK:42845-42867(+):Bird
17   G3                        AGGAGA5567
```